# Why does world become undefined when passed as an argument to a constructor?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, three.js

I'm trying to use threejs and cannonjs, but I'm getting this error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'copy')
>    at World.add.World.addBody (cannon.js:12985:23)
>    at new BothObject (objects.js:15:16)
>    at new Cube (objects.js:33:5)
>    at script.js:7:15
> ```

The relevant code is below:

objects.js

```
class BothObject{
  constructor(shape,geometry,mass,color,scene,world){
    this.scene=scene
    this.world=world
    
    this.physics = new CANNON.Body({
       mass: mass, // kg
    });
    this.physics.shape=shape
    this.geometry = geometry;
    this.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: color});
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry,this.material)
    console.log(world)
    
    this.scene.add(this.mesh)
    this.world.addBody(this.physics)
  }

  
  update(){
    this.mesh.position.copy(this.physics.position)
    this.mesh.quaternion.copy(this.physics.quaternion)
  }
  
}

class Sphere extends BothObject{
  constructor(radius,mass,color,scene,world){
    super(new CANNON.Sphere(radius/2),new THREE.SphereGeometry(radius),mass,color,scene,world)
  }
}

class Cube extends BothObject{
  constructor(width,height,depth,mass,color,scene,world){
    super(new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(width/2,height/2,depth/2)),new THREE.BoxGeometry(width,height,depth),mass,color,scene,world)
  }
}
```

script.js:

```
console.log("start")
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 'skyblue' );
var world = new CANNON.World();
world.gravity.set(0,0,-9.82);
var gground = new Cube(100,100,0.1,"green",scene,world)//it's gground because I have another variable named ground
```

(script.js is run after objects.js)

(both of them aren't run as modules)

When I log world in script.js, it seems fine, but when I log it in Cube or BothObject, it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number of arguments doesn't seem to match

```
(width, height, depth, mass, color,   scene, world) // Cube constructor
(100,   100,    0.1,         "green", scene, world) // new Cube
```

Use typescript to catch mistakes like this

Comment: _"Use typescript to catch mistakes like this"_ ... not necessarily. A good IDE and jsDoc annotations already come in handy (in terms of getting support from an development environment). But the one big and real thing which actually helps is **proper testing** (especially in terms of shaping the correct mindset) and **reading the documentation** (in order to not run into problems like the one experienced by the OP).